# Android checking checkbox multiple times and changing colors from xml file

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

I'm trying to have a checkbox that is red when the app starts up. It is a custom circle checkbox, and they're in xml files. If the user clicks it, then it will turn to yellow. If the user clicks it again, then it will turn green. I'm trying to have the checkbox when clicked to not necessarily be unchecked, but to have it checked every time a user clicks on it. I don't know if this is possible or not. I have been researching how to check a checkbox multiple times and haven't found anything.

Here is how I'm trying to check if is checked more than once.

```
chkInProgess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count = 0;
            if (chkInProgess.isChecked()){
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 1) {
                chkInProgess.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_yellow_checkbox);
            }
            if (count == 2){
                chkInProgess.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_green_checkbox);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my checkbox code.

```
           <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkInProgess"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/inProgress"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtGather"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_red_checkbox"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            />
```

Here is my circle xml code. The yellow and green checkbox xml code is similar just different hex values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <corners android:radius="1dp" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#FFF" />
                <solid android:color="#dc7174"/>
                <size
                    android:width="23dp"
                    android:height="23dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item
            android:width="8dp"
            android:height="2dp"
            android:top="14dp"
            android:left="4dp">
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="45">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#fff"/>
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>

        <item
            android:width="13dp"
            android:height="2dp"
            android:top="12dp"
            android:left="7dp">
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="-45">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#fff"/>
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

</selector>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So what is the problem? Your check boxes don't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure entirely what output you're seeing, but you should have the int count initialized outside of your onClick(View v) method. You are re-initializing the count every time it's ran, so it would probably only ever be red or yellow.

Comment: That answered my question! But I also have a question for having the checkbox when I click it to not have it go unchecked but to every time the user clicks it it turns colors. So, I am wondering if there is a way to make sure that it stays checked but every time you click it, it will change the colors.

Comment: I figured it out. I had an else if statement after the first if statement saying if (!chkInProgress.isChecked) { chkInProgress.setChecked(true); count++;} and that worked! Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you could figure it out.